# Mfc application building in defug mode but not in release mode?

Tags: mfc, visual-studio-2005

Mfc application is showing following error when buil in release mode

Error   152 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SHGetPathFromIDList referenced in function "public: class ATL::CStringT > > __cdecl CCopyFile::DoBrowse(void)" (?DoBrowse@CCopyFile@@QAA?AV?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC@_WV?$ChTraitsOS@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@XZ)   CopyFile.obj

Error   153 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol SHGetPathFromIDList   IflawFileDialog.obj
Error   154 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol SHGetPathFromIDList   NewFile.obj
Error   155 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SHBrowseForFolder referenced in function "public: class ATL::CStringT > > __cdecl CCopyFile::DoBrowse(void)" (?DoBrowse@CCopyFile@@QAA?AV?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC@_WV?$ChTraitsOS@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@XZ) CopyFile.obj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the debug/release linker input dependencies for your project. The release one is probably missing shell32.lib